# Some special Hecke groups

Tags: modular-forms

Any reference for the Hecke group generated by

$z \mapsto -\frac 1 z, \quad z \mapsto z + \frac 2 p$

for $p$ an odd prime? I am conscious that these groups are not discrete.
I am interested by the modular forms under these groups.

Comment: If you are looking for texts/papers, you might consider adding the reference-request tag.  It may also help to be more specific about what you'd like to know/find in the text/paper.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please review [ask].  Providing more context can help Readers aim responses at level commensurate with your background.  If you are going to stick around, learning [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for mathematical notation and expressions will improve readability.